# exp:assets:files fixed_order parameter not working

Tags: assets, parameters

Assets 2.6 
EE 2.9.3

I have the following test code in an otherwise empty template

```
{exp:assets:files fixed_order="3922|834|3991" }
<p>{file_id}</p>
{/exp:assets:files}
```

I would expect it to output in the order of the [fixed_order parameter](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/module/files.html) but it does not instead I see this:

834

3922

3991

Any idea why this is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you need to supply a folder_id

```
Note: Either the folder or folder_id param must be present for {exp:assets:files} to output anything.
```